# How to define member array size at runtime

Tags: c++, arrays

Let's say I have a class that has a member which is an array. Is it possible to define its size upon construction/at run-time, in the following way:

```
class myClass {
    private:
        int myArray[n]
    public:
        myClass();
        someOtherMethod();
};
```

Where n is a variable that is defined based on user input. If not, what would be the best alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a vector.

```
class myClass {
    private:
        std::vector<int> myArray;
    public:
        myClass();
        someOtherMethod();
};

myClass::myClass (int size)
    : myArray (size)
{ 
    ...
}
```

Then, you can fill in the vector as you would an array. Alternatively, as Nawaz points out, use `reserve()`, which reserves space for new elements, and/or `push_back()`, which adds elements onto the back, one at a time.

Comment: Why `resize()`? Why not `reserve()`?

Comment: @Nawaz, depends how you fill it. Either works, although you could fill it like an array with `resize()`.

Comment: If you use `resize()`, then why not use mem-initializer-list as `myClass::myClass (int size) : myArray(size) {}`. It is better.

Comment: @Nawaz, that's true. It really doesn't add any complexion. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 10):

It depends.

Semantically, there are 3 types of arrays:

- arrays with a size fixed at compile time
- arrays with a size fixed at runtime
- arrays with a dynamic size

C++ directly supports the first and third cases, respectively with regular arrays and the `std::vector` class.

C also supports the second type with two constructs:

- variable length arrays (on the stack)
- the oldie struct hack or *tail-padding*

I would advise, in C++, using the `std::vector` class in your case. It provides more than what you need, but is simpler to use.

On the other hand, you can still use tail-padding, even in C++. It does require careful engineering though.

Answer (score 1):

The class template `std::vector` is designed for this purpose.

```
class myClass {
    private:
        std::vector<int> myArray;
    public:
        myClass(int size);
        someOtherMethod();
};

myClass::myClass(int size) : myArray(size)
{
}
```