# How can I make an array with size defined at runtime?

Tags: c++

I have writen this code

```
struct Personalidadbeta{
    int A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, L, M, N, O, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4,Extraversion;
};

const int Cantidad = personalidadalfa.Extraversion * 24;
```

It was done to convert that variable into a constant, but when I want to create a array of structs with that variable "Cantidad" it makes and error witch tells that the variable isnt a constant and it has to be it to run;

```
void crearPersonalidadBeta(){


    Personalidadbeta personalidadbeta[Cantidad];

}
```

How can I do to make that kind of array of structs?

Comment: Could you just use a `vector` instead?

Comment: The size of your array must be sized with a value that is constant **at compile time**. Otherwise you must either use a dynamic array (with `new`) or just use a `vector`, which I would recommend for other reasons as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is X/Y situation , you want to do X , initially so you tried Y and as it didn't worked , you want to know how to fix Y .

For your initial problem :

```
vector<Personalidadbeta> personalidadbeta;
personalidadbeta.resize(Cantidad);
```

you can know use `personalidadbeta` like an array(i.e you can `personalidadbeta[index]` and so..

Read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

One of many advantages of doing it this way is you don't have to free memory manually.

Here is another SO question , similar to this :

[How to define member array size at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374320/how-to-define-member-array-size-at-runtime)